# Find object that provides inherited property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given an object with an unknown number of prototype parents, and a property name that is known to be implemented on one of the parents, what's the best way to find that specific parent?

eg.

```
var a = { x: 'foo' };
var b = {};
var c = { y: 'bar' };
var d = { z: 'baz' };
var e = {};
b.__proto__ = a;
c.__proto__ = b;
d.__proto__ = c;
e.__proto__ = d;
alert(e.y); // 'bar'
```

Given only a reference to `e`, I want to find `c`, since it is where the value of `e.y` actually comes from.  (The objects are created normally; I'm just using `__proto__` for illustrative purposes in this example.)  In reality there can be any number of levels between `c` and `e`.

(And in case it helps, in reality `e` is an AngularJS `$scope`, so an alternate way of framing the question is to find the specific parent scope that provides a particular inherited scope property.)

Answer (score 0):

My naive answer would be something like the following:

```
function findOwnProperty(o, p) {
    while (o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            return o;
        }
        o = o.__proto__; // or o.$parent for scopes
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, or is there something that does this already in some library?

Comment: Just for curious.. why did you answered your question at the same time that you posted? Couldn't it be just an edit on your question?

Comment: Seems like a code review question, since you aren't having issues with your code (presumptive thinking). May be an answer on jsperf as well.

Comment: I think your answer is also wrong, __proto__ is a legacy feature, I wouldn't use it, there is Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)